# CSS text whitespace expands to fill

Tags: css, text, space, expand

I have a table cell containing a paragraph of text. At the end of the paragraph I have a word count. Like this:

From The Analects of Confucious: The Master wanted to settle among the nine barbarian tribes of the East. Someone said: "It is wild in those parts, how would you cope?" The Master said: "How could it be wild, once a gentleman has settled there?" (44)

Depending on the zoom and page width and user's screen size, the last line will probably have some white space after it. I want the count to be positioned over to the right, after the white space.

I could list a few things I've tried, but why? since none of them worked at all.

Comment: can you please update your question and put some snippets and required screenshot for more clarification.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to introduce a code snippet here and I think it's clear as is. Ditto for a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `float:right` on the word count element?